Is it possible to create your own flask/glassware? Has anyone done it recently?
There are alot of flasks/glassware out there, which serve different purposes. Whether thats the Erlenmeyer flask used in titration, invented by Emil Erlenmeyer; or the Schlenk flask used in air-sensitive chemistry, invented by Wilhelm Schlenk. Most of these glasswares come, and get their names, from processes invented by scientists/chemists/researchers. I was wondering whether there is any way of inventing your own flask or glassware of sorts(ofcourse assuming that you have a novel process or experimental setup)? And then how could one get it recognised officially? Has any chemist or scientist done it in the 21st century? Also lastly, are there any companies which designs(or custom make) glassware for your as per your needs!

Glass blowers can fabricate pretty much any desired glass vessel, if they are clearly told what is wanted, e.g., via good drawings, and if cost is no object.

Yeah, that makes sense! Thanks.

However @EdV you cant get it officially named after yourself can you?

Scientific humbleness requires that someone else associate it with your name. Good scientists are often humble people. The fake ones have to beat their drum.

That is quite insightful and right. Regardless, have there been any scientists in the recent century/time, who have been associate to any apparatus in the lab?

I second what @AChem said. I’m pretty sure the Klein bottle was not named by Klein. Same for Dewer flask, etc.

There are glassblowers who are very happy to make specialized equipment at reasonable prices. I have had specialized stills made to recover solvents. Simple glassblowing used to be part of chemistry labs. If you invent something you can name it.

There are many commercial glass-blowing studios and labs -- some commercial, some associated with a school for specialized labware, some for artistic endeavors. Take a class -- it's not hjard to get started! (At a museum school, I taught beginning lampwork.) BTW, you can get Klein labware, for use in the multiverse: https://www.kleinbottle.com . Make your own glass harmonica, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_harmonica, and play Eine Klein Nachtmusik.

EdV, jimchmst, DrMoishe Pippik. Thanks for all the inputs.
